# Access Special Charaters in object key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an Object like this -

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
         [links] => SimpleXMLElement Object
         (
              [@attributes] => Array
              (
                [total-matched] => 5
                [records-returned] => 5
                [page-number] => 1
              )
         )
    )
```

I tried the following statement but it's printing empty object -

```
     print_r($data->links->{'@attributes'});
```

It's just printing blank object as below -

```
   SimpleXMLElement Object{
   }
```

How to fix it and access the 'total-matched' element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example

```
echo (string)$data->links->attributes()['total-matched'];
echo (string)$data->links->attributes()['records-returned'];
echo (string)$data->links->attributes()['page-number'];
```

Comment: This produced the syntax error for square brackets but the following statement worked. Thanks for the Hint. So I accept your answer as correct one.

     echo $data->links->attributes()->{'total-matched'};

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I didn't get any error with my example. May be its php version issue. I am using 5.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to `print` the elements individually , you can go with this..

```
echo (string)$data->links->attributes()->total-matched; //prints 5
echo (string)$data->links->attributes()->records-returned; //prints 5
echo (string)$data->links->attributes()->page-number; //prints 1
```

Don't forget to do the casting to `string` as shown.